# How do I make my raspberry pi invisible on a LAN?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking

How do I make my RaspberryPi running Raspbian invisible on my LAN? Or, if that's impossible, at least customize what information is given from it?

Comment: As you stated the question, the most logical answer is "do not connect your RPi to the LAN". You should explain what you're trying to do, so that it will be obvious what kind of communication you want to allow, and what should be blocked or otherwise 'invisible'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial way to do that is to shut down `eth0` and `wlan0`.

If you want to listen to traffic, you can bring the interfaces up but don't assign any addresses to them. You can then run tools like `tcpdump` on the interfaces.

If that's not what you want, you should be more specific with your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the firewall `iptables` to make the RasPi invisible to the network in fine-grained steps by adding rules to it. For example to suppress ping responses you can add this rule:

```
rpi ~$ sudo iptables --append INPUT --protocol icmp --jump DROP
```

Now if you try to ping the RasPi from another device it will not response.